# Having issue with Single Sign On configuration in a custom policy for Azure ADB2C

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have two different redirect URIs in my webapp like localhost:4200 and localhost:4201. Trying to have single-sign-on for these two. Based on this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-azure-ad-b2c-session-behavior, I
changed my session behavior and SSO configurations and added a UserJourneyBehaviors element inside of the RelyingParty element. It still asking to sign-in localhost:4201, though i have signed in localhost:4200

```
<UserJourneyBehaviors>
      <SingleSignOn Scope="Tenant"/>
      <SessionExpiryType>Absolute</SessionExpiryType>
      <SessionExpiryInSeconds>1200</SessionExpiryInSeconds>
      <ScriptExecution>Allow</ScriptExecution>
</UserJourneyBehaviors>
```

Comment: Make sure your login request to `/authorize` endpoint does not contain `prompt=login` query parameter.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT .. Yeah it doesn't have that parameter

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT - And these are those query parameters (client_id,redirect_uri,response_type,scope,state,nonce ,response_mode)

Comment: Do you mean the app is asking you to sign in (click the login link), or when you click login in the second app, AAD B2C is asking for credentials?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT - its asking when I am clicking second app. Actually I am using sms login(passwordless) , I figured that i should have keep me signed option to be checked .. normal sms login has two pages.. i am able to add keep me signed option in page1 html but  i want it to be added in page2 html because i want sms login to be one page process so i don't want page1..is that possible?

Comment: You need to manage sessions at the technical profile level. Adding Session Management to technical profiles allows B2C to know what to run or skip during Single Sign On scenarios. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-reference-sso